# How to enter url as global parameters

Tags: karate

I had gone through below. 
https://github.com/intuit/karate/

How to enter url as parameter?

Here is my feature file.@demo
Feature: Test feature

Background:
* configure ssl = true

Scenario: Verify my service is up and running

Given url 'https://qa.mygroupservices.int/Version'
When method get
Then status 200

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation, refer to the heading "[Configuration](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration)".

For example like in the [demo](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/karate-config.js) this can be your `karate-config.js`:

```
function() {
  return { myUrl: 'https://qa.mygroupservices.int/Version' };
}
```

Then you can do

```
Given url myUrl
```